# Chips vs Checkboxes inside Dropdowns for Filtering Search?

Tags: search, filter, dropdown, tags

There are hundreds of filter tags to choose from. Since these tags are an unexpected feature for the user, they must be easily seen. I plan on giving them a Search Bar. Additionally, for most popular tags, I plan on having chips beneath the search bar (for ten chips) in a horizontal slider. Is this the best option, or should I display a vertical list of fully visible tag options to choose from?

Comment: Hello! Welcome to UXSE! Do you have any mocks or wireframes of your ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer **Chips** as best option.

Also, you can review **material design**

---

Especially for Filtering search purpose

**+** User selected chips appended to the search input are more user friendly

**+** We do not need to show the selected option

**-** With checkboxes this thing is not presentable

**+** Also we can add <kbd>x</kbd> remove action, so the users can directly remove any selected keyword.

**-** With checkboxes we need to show a list for checkbox options to uncheck

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why you prefer Chips over checkboxes?

Comment: I added few explanations in my answer, see 2nd image which not so good but i hope you get what want to show.